# I am try to get user token for apple music API, i have already generated valid developer token from python terminal commands

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

I am using first time apple music api in my IOS app. I have already generate developer token with the help of python commands.

i am getting error every time when request for the user token "An error occurred when requesting user token: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 7.)"

my developer token look like as "esfd.................................................................................Mpo"

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *)

{

 SKCloudServiceController().requestUserToken(forDeveloperToken: 
 developerToken, completionHandler: { (userToken, error) in

    print("An error occurred when requesting user token: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

})

}

else 
{    

SKCloudServiceController().requestPersonalizationToken(forClientToken: developerToken, withCompletionHandler: { (userToken, error) in

 print("An error occurred when requesting user token: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

})


}
```

Please anyone help me ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it,

Main reason for that "SKErrorDomain error 7" error is your subscription plan.

If you are not subscriber of apple music and you want to get music user token then you always get same type of error.

Comment: Not full answer, the problem may have many reasons, not only subscription

Comment: Might be, but in my case i did tried everything,  i was got music user token after subscribe the iTunes music.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of develop token. I fixed it by using https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator. At the beginning, i use another ruby generator to get develop token. I test ok by using curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340", but also get (SKErrorDomain error 7.) in sample code. Now it is ok. The ruby generator doesn’t work with requesting user tokens:https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator/issues/4

Comment: But how to check is the developer token valid? Can't find the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderYakovlev did you find the correct answer?